# UIView animateWithDuration results in the same location every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView called logoview.

```
[logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(100,100)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:1
                        options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         [logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(0, 3232)];


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
```

I'm trying to animate it with the above code. It results in the object moving to the center from the topleft corner everytime. No matter what cords I ser in the animation section.... I'm using storyboard.

My end goal is to simply show the logo in the center. Then raise the logo up like on the Skype, and facebook logins revealing the login fields. However no matter what values I put for

```
[logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(0, 3232)];
```

It just goes to the center.

I also just tried:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:1
                        options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         [logoview setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -80)];


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
```

Which works to lift the logoview but it also offsets it down quite bit... Making it offcenter.

Entire .m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Couple
//
//  Created by Michael Latman on 4/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Michael Latman. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Rounded corners!
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    //lol.layer.cornerRadius = 90;
    //lol.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //[logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(100,100)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:1
                        options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{

                         [logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(0, 1)];


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:1.0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
    [logoview setCenter:CGPointMake(logoview.center.x, logoview.center.y - 80.0)];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Works.. thanks to @matt too

Answer (score 3):

Well, one problem is that `viewDidLoad` is way too soon. You want to wait until at least `viewDidAppear`. Your interface hasn't got its real size yet in `viewDidLoad`. All that's happened is that your view controller *has* a view; the view is not yet even in the interface, let alone visible to the user.

Comment: Alright I did this... I turned off auto-layout and it started animating properly...

Comment: @Michael you might find the discussion of autolayout in my book useful: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout And also (especially) the combat between animation and constraints: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout Basically I regard this as a major flaw in how constraints are implemented in iOS: you try to change a view's frame and the constraints change it back again.